# GraphQL vue apollo query and mutation same view

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, graphql, apollo, vue-apollo

I'm just starting to use GraphQL with Apollo and Vue, so it might be a "stupid" question but I can't figure how to do.

How can I do inside the same view, a query to fetch one object, and update it using a mutation

Let's say I have a simple schema

```
type Product {
   id: ID!
   title: String!
   description: String
}
```

And a vue component

```
<script>

  // GraphQL query
  const ProductQuery = gql `
    query($id: ID){
      Product(id: $id) 
      {
        id
        title
        description
      }
    }
  `;

  const UpdateProductQuery = gql `
    mutation updateProduct($id: ID!, $title: String!, $description: String) {
      updateProduct(
        id: $id,
        title: $title,
        description: $description,
      ) {
        id
      }
    }
  `;

export default {
    data() {
      return {
        Product: {},
      };
    },
    apollo: {
        Product: {
            query: ProductQuery,
            variables() {
                  id: 1234,
           };
        },
    },
    methods: {
        updateProduct() {

          this.$apollo.mutate({
             mutation: UpdateProductQuery,
             variables: {
                id: this.Product.id,
                title: this.Product.title,
                description: this.Product.description,
            },
          })
        }
   }
};
</script>
```

Now how am I supposed to write the template part ? Can I link the Product object to a v-model inside an input ?

```
<template>
   <section>
       <input v-model="product.title"></input>
       <input v-model="product.description"></input>
      <button @click="updateProduct">Update</button>
   </section>
</template>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally found out that data from the query is immutable, that's why I can't update them.

The solution is to create a new object using Object.assign or lodash cloneDeep.

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely on the right track!
One thing I notice is that `Product` is capitalized in your JS, but not in your template. So either update your template like so:

```
<template>
  <section>
    <input v-model="Product.title"></input>
    <input v-model="Product.description"></input>
    <button @click="updateProduct">Update</button>
  </section>
</template>
```

...or make `product` lowercase in your JS (which I personally prefer).

Also, I believe you need to use [reactive parameters](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-apollo#reactive-parameters) in this case. `variables` will need to be a function rather than an object.

```
variables() {
  return {
    id: this.Product.id,
    title: this.Product.title,
    description: this.Product.description
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. Yes, I actually changed it to lowercase. However on my updateProduct() method, 'this.product' doesn't have the new value. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong

Comment: @Jerome, I updated my answer. I think that the use of "reactive parameters" is the key.